# Как работают обертки BufferedOutputStream и DataOutputStream?

Tags: java, io

В большинстве UML диаграмм классов байтовых потоков, которые мне удалось найти, нарисовано что `BufferedOutputStream` и `DataOutputStream` это наследники `FilterOutputStream`, но при этом оба они вроде как используются и для `FileOutputStream` и других классов напрямую реализующих интерфейс `OutputStream`.

Вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю что каждый класс напрямую реализующий `OutputStream` имеет свой `BufferedOutputStream` и `DataOutputStream` или по крайней мере может быть в них обернут... Или это как-то по-другому работает?

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что каждый класс напрямую реализующий `OutputStream`

Реализуют интерфейсы, а `OutputStream` – это класс, а не интерфейс, следовательно, реализовать `OutputStream` невозможно. Другие классы могут наследоваться от (абстрактного) класса `OutputStream`.

Классы `BufferedOutputStream` и `DataOutputStream` имеют конструкторы:

```
BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out)
```

и

```
DataOutputStream(OutputStream out)
```

, следовательно, любые классы, имеющие в иерархии наследования выше них класс `OutputStream`, могут быть обернуты в `BufferedOutputStream` и `DataOutputStream`.

`FilterOutputStream` (и `FilterInputStream`) используется для создания  некоторой *прослойки* между потоками, с помощью которой, например, можно [осуществлять манипуляции с данными](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/io/writingFiltered.html). С помощью него же можно реализовать поток, который [не будет закрываться](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17563849/7129209) при закрытии внешнего потока.

Потоки `FilterOutputStream` и `FilterInputStream` являются примерами паттерна проектирования Декоратор.

Comment: Да пардон конечно OutputStream это класс... Все таки мне вот что непонятно: если зайти в доки то там BufferedOutputStream на пример,   является наследником FilterOutputStream, но почему именно его а не какого-то другого? И главное - если в своем конструкторе тот-же BufferedOutputStream принимает OutputStream то зачем он вообще оказался в этой иерархии? Почему им не иметь такую-же "зависимость" как String и StringBilder на пример? Не какую кроме аргумента в конструкторе... Что в этом FilterOutputStream такого особенного что он делает..?

Comment: @Павел, Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Я кажется понял. FilterOutputStream это абстрактный класс что-бы BufferedOutputStream и DataOutputStream могли быть адаптерами для вышестоящих... Кажется так.

Comment: @Павел, `FilterOutputStream` – не абстрактный класс, а в остальном, грубо говоря, верно.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Без нее я бы завтра на зачете облажался по полной...